# get name and device file path of usb device attached

Tags: command-line, usb

if i run the common `lsusb` i get something like:

> Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter

but it doesn't show the device file path (i.e ttyUSB0). does it exist a command which does this?

about `dmesg` and `udevadm info` they are too verbose.

I would rather to have a simpler output, the best would be to append just the device file path to the output of lsusb, something like:

> Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Please try: `lsusb -t`

Comment: output without port: `/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ch341, 12M
`

Comment: Are you looking for the actual physical port, or the corresponding `ttyUSB` device path?  That isn't the "port", that's the "Device file path"

Comment: yes, my mistake (due to ignorance) i am editing my question

Comment: I think `dmesg -w` is the easy way but check this answer for more options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them

Answer (score 2):

a lot of copy/paste brought me again here hoping that this would be helpful for others and also to improve my code

I used the almost perfect code from the answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0) and added/removed some little stuff

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] || [[ "$devname" == "input/"* ]] || [[ "$devname" == "video0"* ]] || exit
        
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        
        busnum="$(udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/$devname) | awk -F "==" '/busnum/ {gsub("\"","");print $2}' | head -1)"
        devnum="$(udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/$devname) | awk -F "==" '/devnum/ {gsub("\"","");print $2}' | head -1)"
        bus_dev=${busnum}:${devnum}
        lsusb="$(lsusb -s $bus_dev)"
        
        echo "$lsusb - /dev/$devname"
    )
done
```

output:

> Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter - /dev/ttyUSB0

NOTE: i don't have any unix experience so if you would like to improve the code please do!